# Sort Parse Query based on difference with Float

Tags: ios, sorting, parse-platform, pfquery

I want to sort the results of my Parse Query based on the scalar distance from the field `temperature` to my variable  `referenceTemp`

I tried the following, which of course does not work, but it illustrates my intention

```
var referenceTemp = 47.89
var query = PFQuery(className: "Temperatures")
query.orderByAscending("abs(temperature - referenceTemp)")
```

How can I do it? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Can't be done at the database level.  I think the only alternative is to get the results and apply that sort in memory.

Comment: You want all results though, or to filter some out? Just sort by temp...

Comment: I would filter some out, but it is then important that I get the n items with temperature closest to referenceTemp ... on the plus side, whereyKey seems like it accepts expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this on the database level... but you can do it with two queries:

```
var referenceTemp = 47.89
var query = PFQuery(className: "Temperatures")
query.greaterThan(referenceTemp);
query.orderByAscending();
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        //Get the scalar distance for each, store
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}

query.lessThan(referenceTemp);
query.orderByDescending();
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock...
```

Once you have both the closest above and below, and their scalar distances, you could use a hash or an NSDictionary with keys of scalar distance and values of the objects. Order as needed and you're there in only 2 queries.